# Inserting 2 New Columns with unique values in a select statement

Tags: sql

Let's say I have Table1 and it looks like this :

[image]

Now I want to add two new columns in a select statement 
and make it look like this in a temporary table :

[image]

A= 1 in New Column 1 and "Ball" in New Column 2
B should be left blank in both new columns
Z = 17A in New Column 1 and "Soccer" in New Column 2 
and etc.

I did the following :

```
    Select [Column1],
    '' AS [New Column 1] ,
    '' AS [New Column 2],

    from Table1
```

However, all this does is create the two new columns with blank values:

[image]

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Nothing on Google in any of the RDBMS docs on how to add columns to a table?

Comment: Where do these values come from?

Comment: So you want your sql statement to just pull random strings from the ether and inject them into a result set??

Comment: I am sorry. I did try to google and will continue doing research on this. I used random table names because I thought that was not important. Column 1 has hundreds of items names and new column 1 is supposed to be a column where I add different item names and new column 2 is supposed to be item description.  I am sorry if this is stupid but this is a genuine question from me.

Comment: I am working with a genuine database but changed all the column names and table names. That is what I have been doing with my past questions here.

Comment: You're probably better off looking into a JOIN on another table that has the relationship you want.  Otherwise your select statement will wind up much more complicated than the results

Comment: Thank you for your response! Really appreciate it! I like your idea but there is no other table with the relationship I want, unfortunately. Maybe I can create another table just for this but hopefully, there is another way.

Comment: You would have to create a table.  Because if you don't you have to make a case statement for each row of each value for the first column and again for the second column. Basically, the easiest solution is to create the second table.  Otherwise a case statement will be so much more complicated.

Comment: You can even use a LEFT JOIN and in the second table only have the values you want to have values for the other two columns

Comment: Thank you MitoxBeyond. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

```
    Select [Column1],
    CASE
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’A’ ) then ‘1’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’B’ ) then ‘’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’Z’ ) then ‘17A’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’D’ ) then ‘19b’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’F’ ) then ‘oxx’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’O’ ) then ‘’
    Else ‘’
    END AS [New Column 1],

    CASE
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’A’ ) then ‘Ball’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’B’ ) then ‘’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’Z’ ) then ‘Soccer’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’D’ ) then ‘Jaja’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’F’ ) then ‘Hello’
    WHEN ([Column1] = ’O’ ) then ‘’
    ELSE ‘’
    END AS [New Column 2]

    From Table1
```